# How do i get the headers from the error callback of subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, rxjs5

I want to handle any error responses from the server after a user create post response. The post is made in the UserService createUser() method. There any errors are catched with the `catch` method after which a new error is thrown. I've read that this is neccessary otherwise the success callback within the subscribe method will be activated regardless of an error.

I am using Visual studio code as my IDE for this project and when you type in the `.` operator after a variable it gives a list of any methods it can call on that variable. The success callback variable has all the methods expected, including headers. The error callback only has html. So my question is: how do i get the headers out of the error? I need access to the headers because my custom header message is sent in the headers. This needs to be done within subscribe method thats situated within the component controller because when i handle the error in the service i cannot make an error message popup appear. Here is my code:

The code on the component controller side:

```
  createUser():void{
    this.loading = true;
      this.userService.createUser(new UserCreateDTO(this.userForm.get('userName').value, 
                this.userForm.get('emailAddress').value, 
                this.userForm.get('password').value))
      .subscribe(
        success =>{
            this.msgs.push({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail: `User ${this.userForm.get('userName').value} succesfully created.`});
        },
        error =>{
          let errorMessage: string = error.???
            this.msgs.push({severity:'error', summary:'Error', detail: `error`});
        }),
        () =>{
          this.loading = false;
        }
  }
}
```

The questionmarks indicate that no method suggestions appear aside from method html.

The code on the service side, where the post is being made:

```
  createUser(newUser: UserCreateDTO): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.post<Response>(this.authUrl + "/user/create", newUser)
            .catch((error:any) =>{
                return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            });
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So headers would be available on a `HttpErrorResponse` which is what you're getting back in the .catch but you are marking it is as type `any` so you won't see code suggestions.  Try `catch((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>` in your service to see what's available.

You are then replacing the `HttpErrorResponse` with a simple `Error` object which you're just giving the status to as a message (which would be available as `error.message` in your error handler in the component). I think you should define the error detail you want in the service and then just use `error.message` in the component.

Comment: can i catch this HttpErrorResponse object in the error callback section if i define error as a HttpErrorResponse object as well?

Comment: ...you shouldn't. Your service knows about HTTP calls and things like that. Your component shouldn't. Imagine if your service wasn't always making a HTTP call at all but sometimes looking in local storage for cached data.  Then a totally different type of error might be created if something went wrong.  Use your catch function to create a new `Error` (like you're doing) with a message that makes sense and that you can display in the popup

Comment: if you want more control in the client then you can do something like this (which is what we do in my workplace): https://blog.michalszalkowski.com/java-script/angular-throwing-application-specific-errors/ .

Comment: Using custom errors lets you have abstract error types NotFound, NotAuthorized without it mattering to the component HOW those errors occurred

Comment: `export class CrazyShitError extends AppBaseError` haha

Comment: We don't have that one at my work!  But `NotFound`, `BadInput`, `NotAuthorized`, `NotAuthenticated` and then the generic `AppError` for the ones that you can't do anything about gracefully.

Comment: I appreciate you sharing the link, but its not useful for me.  The errors that i'm trying to handle are very specific. When someone creates a new user account someone could send a username thats already in use or an email thats already in use. Responding to this  error with a simple `badRequest` or `internal_server` error just wouldn't be very informative.I think i am going to try a different approach, namely just send a custom status json object as a response, with 2 fields: Sucessfull:boolean and info: string. That the server can tell exactly whats wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174324/discussion-between-nick-and-maurice).